# Docker tutum/wordpress container issues with apache2 and supervisor

Tags: wordpress, apache, docker, supervisord, tutum

I'm new to Docker and I've been working on a Wordpress site based on the tutum/wordpress image for a couple of months now.  I had edited the wordpress site as recently as last week; however, now when I try to display the website I get nothing.

I haven't changed anything since last week when it was last working.  I can SSH into the Ubuntu server just fine. I can see the container is running and I can attach to the container.  Once in the container I have verified that Apache and MySQL are running. I can navigate through the file system and Wordpress is still there.

It's almost as if the container isn't accessible from the web but I'm at a loss as to where to begin troubleshooting.

UPDATE: It appears to be a problem with supervisord and apache.  The docker logs say apache is in a fatal state due to too many retries; however, using sudo service apache2 status indicates that Apache is running.  After issuing an /etc/init.d/apache2 stop command Apache is still running.  I can't get it to stop. ps -A doesn't show apache running, only supervisor. I'm still quite confused.

```
Docker Port: 80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:80
```

Docker Logs:

```
2016-05-12 20:01:39,534 INFO waiting for mysqld to die
=> Using an existing volume of MySQL
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:295: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2016-05-12 20:02:16,501 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2016-05-12 20:02:16,501 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-mysqld.conf" during parsing
2016-05-12 20:02:16,501 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-apache2.conf" during parsing
Unlinking stale socket /var/run/supervisor.sock
2016-05-12 20:02:16,839 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2016-05-12 20:02:16,839 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2016-05-12 20:02:16,839 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2016-05-12 20:02:17,847 INFO spawned: 'mysqld' with pid 9
2016-05-12 20:02:17,853 INFO spawned: 'apache2' with pid 10
2016-05-12 20:02:17,957 INFO exited: apache2 (exit status 0; not expected)
2016-05-12 20:02:19,303 INFO success: mysqld entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-05-12 20:02:19,308 INFO spawned: 'apache2' with pid 392
2016-05-12 20:02:19,396 INFO exited: apache2 (exit status 0; not expected)
2016-05-12 20:02:21,404 INFO spawned: 'apache2' with pid 394
2016-05-12 20:02:21,491 INFO exited: apache2 (exit status 0; not expected)
2016-05-12 20:02:24,500 INFO spawned: 'apache2' with pid 395
2016-05-12 20:02:24,586 INFO exited: apache2 (exit status 0; not expected)
2016-05-12 20:02:25,588 INFO gave up: apache2 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

Comment: can you post `docker port container_id` and `docker logs container_id`

Comment: can you provide the configuration file of supervisor?

Answer (score 0):

I found and fixed the problem but I don't know how or why it became a problem as I've been running this server and container for a couple of months now.

The issue was that supervisord was configured to run apache2; however, there was also an apache2 script in /etc/init.d/

I did an "update-rc.d -f apache2 remove" command while in the /etc/init.d folder to remove this script from the init process on startup.  I then bounced the server and was back in business.